# YAML stage dependsOn other stage but skipped

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Stage is getting skipped eventhough all dependencies seems conditions are present.

Here are rquirements for a pipeline:

- stage 'NextTest' should be run after stage 'FakeTests' completed
- stage 'NextTest' should not depend on 'FakeTests' stage result (even if 'FakeTests' failed 'NextTest' should be run)
- stage 'NextTest' should not run if 'ToSkip' stage failed
- stage 'NextTest' should run if 'ToSkip' stage skipped.

Here is yaml:

```
stages:
- stage: ToSkip
  jobs:
  - job: Skip
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "Something"
- stage: FakeTests
  jobs:
  - job: PassTest
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "Test Passed"
  - job: FailTest
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "Test Failed"
        exit 1
- stage: NextTests
  dependsOn: 
  - FakeTests
  - ToSkip
  condition: | 
    and(
    in(stageDependencies.FakeTests.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped', 'Failed'),
    in(stageDependencies.ToSkip.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    )
  jobs:
  - job: NextPassTest
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "Test Passed"
```

This YAML is used as AzureDevOps pipeline.
However if 'ToSkip' skipped and 'FakeTests' failed 'NextTest' are skipped as well.
Why is that? And how to correct it?
[image: pipeline]

Comment: Nice YAML structure. Yaml is data structure (just like JSON) and does not skip anything on it's own. Tell us to where you feed that Yaml

Comment: It's used at azuredevops pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the stageDependencies JSON structure, there's no key called 'result' under <STAGE_NAME>. you should refer results through

**stageDependencies.<STAGE_NAME>.<JOB_NAME>.result**

```
"stageDependencies": {
    "<STAGE_NAME>": {
        "<JOB_NAME>": {
            "result": "Succeeded|SucceededWithIssues|Skipped|Failed|Canceled",
            "outputs": {
                "stepName.variableName": "value"
            }
        },
        "...": {
            //another job
        }
    },
    "...": {
        //anotherstage
    }
}
```

Try this with your code

```
condition: | 
and(
in(stageDependencies.FakeTests.PassTest.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped', 'Failed'),
in(stageDependencies.FakeTests.FailTest.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped', 'Failed'),
in(stageDependencies.ToSkip.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
)
```

For more information, you might want to checkout [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)